# Using Play-Circe or Circe to Json to JsValue

Tags: scala, playframework, circe

I have the following code i found after discovering circe and trying to implement it into my play application...

```
implicit val TimestampFormat : Encoder[Timestamp] with Decoder[Timestamp] = new Encoder[Timestamp] with Decoder[Timestamp] {
    override def apply(a: Timestamp): Json = Encoder.encodeLong.apply(a.getTime)
    override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[Timestamp] = Decoder.decodeLong.map(s => new Timestamp(s)).apply(c)
}
```

The problem is that the apply method returns Json and there seems to be no way to convert Circe JSON to Plays JsValue.....

How can i use circe to return JsValues or use play to convert a circe Json to a play JsValue?

Comment: What have you already tried about that?

Comment: Are you using Circe or want to do something similar in play-json?

Comment: Solved, sorry. play-circe is meant to be used outside of JsValue structures that was the root of my problem.

I.E Json.Obj(CaseClass.asJson) when Json.obj expects a JsValue
instead it should just be Ok(CaseClass.asJson)

Answer (score 1):

Solved, sorry i was syntactically using circle-play wrong.
Instead of

```
 Ok(Json.obj("data" -> CaseClass.asJson))
```

it should just be...

```
Ok(CaseClass.asJson)
```